# Easy GUI programming in Mac OS X. Targeting Windows Platform

Tags: macos, user-interface

I have a friend who has an entry-level background in programming and is looking for a free **GUI framework** (IDE, GUI toolkit and GUI designer ) that:

- He can use on **Mac OS X** to build **Windows** applications
- It's very **easy** to use.

He is not interested in becoming a programmer, but would like to build an application for his work (not CS-related).

What are some good GUI frameworks/prog. languages he can use?

Comment: what programming language does he know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Qt including Qt Creater and Qt Designer](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is worth a try.

Especially, if your app should finally run cross-platform, on phones or on other embedded devices. Qt natively supports C++, but can also be used with 3rd-party extensions with Python ([PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)) and probably other languages.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac I have to recommend making Cocoa applications in Xcode written in Objective-C. Xcode is free to download and use, you pay if you want to submit applications to the Mac App Store.

I personally use Xcode every day and I think it's a great IDE. Currently has compiler support for Obj-C, C++, C and maybe more (not sure). More importantly for your needs, Xcode does a great job of integrating your code with its build in "interface builder" to help you quickly and easily create a nice UI.

**NOTE:** Xcode includes a new compiler feature (ARC) Automatic Reference Counting which is create for a new user. You can learn the language without having to worry about manual memory management.

Comment: The OP wants to target the Windows platform.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti Ha you've gotta love post answer question edits.

Comment: Yep, they spice StackOverflow with a little nonsense here and there

Comment: Thanks @NSPostWhenIdle and sorry for the last minute change!

Comment: @roseck No problem, sorry I couldn't be more help. I don't know anything about windows development.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend should consider using [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/), a Python binding for the [Qt GUI framework](http://qt.nokia.com/) already mentioned.

With PySide you can use the Qt tools to create GUI elements interactively
and code your application logic in Python, which is a language often appreciated by non-programmers (and programmers too!) for its simplicity and intuitiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode includes a WYSIWYG editor for native controls and views. This was formerly a separate program called Interface Builder, but the editor was moved into the Xcode IDE at version 4.

AppKit is the framework it uses in most cases -- that's Objective-C. It's well supported. Your friend can also use it for source code editing and building and debugging apps. If he wants to write UIs programmatically, Xcode and AppKit are also good options.